# Path Error still the same after replacing path with constant (Module does not exist in the module map)

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, react-redux, environment-variables

I have the following problem, I get:

"Unable to resolve module `nik/env` from `/some/path/constant.js` : Module does not exist in the module map or in these directories `/path/to/project/root`"

In my `constant.js` I do try to do the following:

```
import {
    API_URL,
} from 'nik/env'
```

- so I am basically just trying to get a variable (API_URL) out of my env.

**However**, when I tested this and I replaced the above with a hardcoded variable like so: `const API_URL = 'http://my-api.myserver.com';`, I still get the same error. Namely, that it cannot resolve `nik/env` - but there is no reference to `nik/env` in that file anymore.

Why could this be? Thanks a lot in advance!!

Comment: The problem is the dependency 'nik', is this an alias or a module ? If it's an alias, did you configure well your alias ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by alias, but 'nik/env' is an absolute import path. It still doesn't explain why, when I replace the import with a constant, the error still occurs?